# find textbox control on row specific row on selection of dropdown in cellrenderer event in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have a dropdown in column definition in gridoptions and on the cellrendrer I want to find the textbox control on specific row to disable/enable on the selection of dropdown.